# Script to delete user profiles from Win 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7

We are trying to delete user profiles from our loaner laptops when we get them back and we want them deleted completely (From C user & registry). Please suggest an easy way, preferably a scrip that we can run. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We were manually deleting the profiles but it appears to be a time consuming task, I remember having a script at my previous job but didn't get a chance to explore much about it.

Comment: Thanks. You should then write that script and/or look for one on Internet. If you are stuck when writing that script, come back on StackOverflow and asks a question about your specific problem, sharing what you’ve tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question will likely be closed because it doesn’t meet those guidelines.